# python dataframe substract a column from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe and I want to substract a column from multiple columns
code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('A':[10,20,30],'B':[100,200,300],'C':[15,10,50])

# Create a new A and B columns by sub-stracting C from A and B
df[['newA','newB']] = df[['A','B']]-df['C']
```

Present output:

```
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `sub`

```
df[['newA', 'newB']] = df[['A', 'B']].sub(df['C'],axis=0)
df
Out[114]: 
    A    B   C  newA  newB
0  10  100  15    -5    85
1  20  200  10    10   190
2  30  300  50   -20   250
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option along with the above answer, you can convert column 'C' to a numpy array by doing `df[['C']].values`. Hence the new code would be:

```
df[['newA','newB']] = df[['A','B']]-df[['C']].values
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pandas `.apply()` method. You can pass columns and apply a given function to them, in this case subtracting one of your existing columns. The below should work. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
df[['newA','newB']] = df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: x - df['C'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to  convert `df['C'].values` to the same shape with `df[['A','B']]`.

```py
df[['newA','newB']] = df[['A','B']] - df['C'].values[:, None]
```

```
print(df)

    A    B   C  newA  newB
0  10  100  15    -5    85
1  20  200  10    10   190
2  30  300  50   -20   250
```